# Using Django without a database

Tags: python, django

Is Django a good solution for creating applications that won't use any database and communicate only through an internal API?

Comment: Yes.  Since that's probably not helpful, you might want to provide more details and what your alternative choices are.

Comment: Why not just use any other language, say JavaScript?

Comment: There are other great Python frameworks. Take a look on Flask for example.

Comment: This question might be better at [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/14673/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends what you call 'good'.

However, while you can use django with no database, the object-relational mapper is pretty much its first and foremost advertised feature. Django was designed to produce database-backed web sites, so if you're not going to use a database you might end up dealing with a bunch of unnecessary hassle.

Answer (score 12):

Although there is nothing stopping you from not using a DB in Django, my advice would be: "If you don't need a full stack framework, don't use a full stack framework". Python has *many* excellent microframeworks that might suit your needs better.

This blog post discusses some of them: http://www.konstruktor.ee/blog/python-web-framework-roundup

My personal favorite is Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/, but I have not done much real work with it.

Comment: Using a micro-framework is an excellent suggestion and one I would highly recommend for such a use case.

Comment: That's like saying: if there is a special purpose language that can do the job, then don't use Python. Even if you only use 5% of a tool, it may be the best choice, as long as you can just ignore the remaining 95% (until you need it). Disclaimer: I like monoliths (and I don't like Flask).

Answer (score 0):

From the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/):

> Django is well suited for making database-driven Web sites, as it comes with easy yet powerful ways of performing database queries using Python.

You can use the framework to make a site with some logic in it, but you will be wasting some of its potential. Besides, interacting with the database from Django layer is too easy to ignore it.

Comment: The point is not necessarily related to ease of use. On may also want to exclude a database because it is not needed one does not want a database dependence included in the library (even with sql-lite, that requires extra software installed on a target system). Moreover, including a dummy database for the sake of pragmatics can cause it to be used unexpectedly (for example because the auth app is included), resulting in unanticipated system features (which can be bad). Ergo no db for lean and mean.

Answer (score -4):

Django comes with inbuilt sqllite database. Which doesn't require much configurations. And when it comes to the use django without database then it simply violates the MTV pattern of Django.

Comment: `sqlite` isn't a database you can use in production, it doesn't exactly scale for large websites. And the model doesn't have to come from a database.

Comment: Yes for production purposes sqlite can't be used. It can only be used for development purposes. For large websites postgresql, mysql, oracle are the options.